# Can't Adding data to firestore database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but profiles/undefined has 2.

```
const user = await signUpNewUser(auth, email, password);

    const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, `profiles/${user.uid}`), {
      nama: form.nama,
      createdAt: new Date().getTime().toString(),
    });

    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
```

Comment: In firebase the first segment is a collection and the second is a document and then the third will be the collection likewise odd-numbered segments will be the collections and even-numbered segments will be documented. You are trying to create a collection in the document section.

Comment: Can you ask the question a little more directly? Is your statement before the code an error message you're getting or is that commentary on your code segment?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `addDoc` Firestore generates the ID for the new document for you. If you want to specify the ID yourself (as you do with `user.uid`), use `setDoc` instead:

```
const docRef = await setDoc(collection(db, `profiles/${user.uid}`), {
  nama: form.nama,
  createdAt: new Date().getTime().toString(),
});
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [setting a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document).

Comment: Thanks Frank van Puffelen ! this method worked :)