# How can update new Field data to existing document without overwrite to existing data in firebase-9 by react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I try to update data by adding new Field into existing data in firestore by react native expo
when I try to update by setDoc() , all existing data removed and only newly update one remian
How can update data into same document in firebase
[image: here my firestore data]

can someone guide me how can add new Field  without losing existing data in firestore.

here is my attemp by setDoc

```js
const updateUser = async(key, value) => {
  await addDoc(doc(db,'users',user.uid), { [key]: value })
};
```

I try to add is new Field . how can add new field
I also try as follow

```
 const updateUser = async(key,value)=>{
    const updateRef = doc(db, "users",value);
    await updateDoc(updateRef, {
      [key]: true
    });
   }
```

this is new Field I try to add
[image]

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70144432/cant-adding-data-to-firestore-database/70144645#70144645: "When you call `addDoc` Firestore generates the ID for the new document for you. If you want to specify the ID yourself, use `setDoc` instead."

Comment: @Mises: did you mean to change the call from `addDoc` to `setDoc` in the code here? That sounds like a change that OP themselves should make.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I wrote a summary what i changed so hope he get know that he was using wrong function in code.

Comment: But that should be an answer, not an edit to the question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen He was writing about `setDoc()` func and only in code snippet he had `addDoc()`. If he had an option { merge: true } in code i would point a mistake that he was using wrong func.

Comment: But the original code was `const updateUser = async(key, value) => { await addDoc(doc(db,'users',user.uid), { [key]: value }) };`, so there was no `{ merge: true }` parameter in there.  The fact that they have to use `setDoc(..., { merge: true})` or `updateDoc(...)` is part of the answer. I rolled back that part of your change: please explain in your answer why OP should be using `setDoc` (as you may already have done).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import `firestore` from firebase library

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
```

And then you can get the document reference you need

```
const docRef = firestore().collection('Users').doc('ABC')
```

after that you can update your doc by method `update()`

```
  docRef
  .update({
    age: 31,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('User updated!');
  });
```

Detailed about usage of firestore you can find in this documentation https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage

Answer (score 3):

**You need to set option merge.**

firebase 9+

```js
function updateData(collPath, data) {
    setDoc(doc(db, collPath, data.id), data, { merge: true})
}
```

firebase 8-

```js
function updateData(collPath, data) {
    db.collection(collPath).doc(data.id).set(data, { merge: true })
}
```

And in both of libraries you can use function `updateDoc()` or v8 `...doc().update()`